# Найдут ли поисковые системы плагиат в переведенном тексте? (SEO)

Tags: seo

здравствуйте, если допустим взять текст на английском, перевести его переводчиком на русский (без правки), и залить на сайт, ПС распознают что это ворованный и не уникальный текст?

Comment: Люди-то точно распознают халтуру.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понимаю, но речь в вопросе про ПС

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **[справке Гугл Скопированное содержание](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312)**, сообщается: "*...Само по себе такое содержание, пусть даже скопированное с самых популярных и качественных сайтов, не будет представлять ценности для пользователей, если на вашем сайте не будут предоставляться дополнительные материалы или возможности для работы с ним. Также следует учесть, что вы можете нарушить авторские права. Лучше потратить время и создать оригинальный контент, который выделит ваш сайт из массы других. Это позволит привлечь постоянных посетителей и обеспечить релевантность при поиске в Google*". Далее в этой же справке сообщается, как один из примеров скопированного содержания: "*Сайты, размещающие контент из других источников без **дополнительной обработки***". Но вы планируете переводить текст с английского на русский. Это может обозначать, что вы произвели **дополнительную обработку**. Однако, вы планируете "*перевести его переводчиком на русский (без правки), и залить на сайт*". Это вашей действие, может быть воспринято, как **[Автоматически сгенерированное содержание, согласно справке Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306?hl=ru)**. Один из пример такого содержания из этой справки: "***Текст, который переведен с помощью автоматического инструмента и опубликован без редактирования***". Таким образом, ваш переведённый, но не корректированный текст, **может получить бан/запрет, как нарушение рекомендаций Гугл по обеспечению качества**. Кроме того, пользователя вряд ли захотят вчитываться и разбираться в неправильном русском языке. Ваш веб-сайт с автоматически переведённым текстом, не будет иметь трафика. Возникает вопрос: Зачем нужен подобный веб-сайт? Поэтому, я рекомендую вам **обязательно** корректировать переведённый текст. Основной плюс этой (возможно сложной) работы - это **создание уникального текста**, который привлечёт массу трафика на ваш веб-сайт.